Backpack laravel , How to preview files/upload_multiple?
I am trying to upload multiple files (backpack:5.x )
Files selected. After save, they will show up above. this is the message I am getting after uploading files. How to preview files after upload?
$this->crud->addfield([
 'name'    => 'files',
 'label'   => 'Files',
 'upload'    => true,
 'type'    => 'upload_multiple',
 'disk' => 'uploads',
 ]);


How to save file with original name + date

File with .msg extension is not downloading it is opening in browser



You didn't get a preview of file with this field, just a link to download. If you want to preview an image, you have others fields, like Image Pro amongs others you can see in our documentation
As our docs says:
The uploadMultipleFilesToDisk() method will take care of everything for most use case.
If you wish to have a different functionality, you can delete the method call from your mutator and do your own thing.
Cheers.
